# Delete recently added lines from a text file

Tags: c++, file, text-files, line

I'm writing a program in C++ which writes lines to a text file. In certain circumstances I want it to delete a bunch of recently added lines. The code looks like this:

```
file << "Some line." << endl; // *

// lots of lines might be written to file here

if (condition2)
  // delete all the lines written to file since * including line "Some line."
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you just buffer the new lines instead of adding them and delete or commit at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `seekp` and `tellp` methods of ostream.

I assume your `file` is some sort of fstream.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a pseudo code, since you too didn't give enough info

```
if (condition2)
{
   /*
    1. Read back the file lines till "Some line" marker
       in say, std::vector<std::string> 

    2. Discard other lines after that.

    3. Write the contents of std::vector into the file

  */
}
```